# Select orderId if it has both items bought

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a quite common case of two tables: 'Orders' placed and 'ItemsBought' for each order:

```
Orders: orderId, orderDate, [...]
ItemsBought: boughtId, orderId, itemId, [...]
```

Order can have one or more ItemsBought. Now, I want to select only those orders where users bought BOTH itemId=1 AND itemId=2.

Say, we have such data in ItemsBought table:

```
boughtId | orderId | itemId
---------------------------
1        | 1       | 1
2        | 1       | 2
3        | 1       | 3
4        | 2       | 1
5        | 2       | 3
6        | 2       | 4
```

I need query to return only:

```
orderId
-------
1
```

What would be SQL code in Access 2010?

Comment: You have to be a little more specific about your requirements. In what conditions do you want it and what do you want in the output query? Just orderId = 1?

Comment: I need query to return a list of orderId. I intend to use it in subquery.

Comment: `SELECT orderId FROM ItemsBought` ?

Comment: Is this just a one-off or is this something that needs to be generic enough to work for any input?

Comment: I intend to parametrize it and include in complex query's WHERE clause as a subquery. I just don't know how to set whereclause on the same field twice (thrice etc).

Comment: Are you always only going to be looking for ids 1 and 2?  If not, this is significantly more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT orderId 
FROM ItemsBought
WHERE itemId IN (1,2)
GROUP BY orderId
HAVING COUNT(orderId) = 2;
```

This will only work if you can't have multiple items 1 or 2 in the same orderid.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8132f/2)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, that's the code I need. Simple and elegant. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm positive there is a more efficient way to do this but here's one simple solution. Basically just do an inner join on the two separate subqueries which pull back the lines you want.

The results will be the intersection between the two sets or in otherwords those orders where both items were found.

```
Select orderId
From 
(
Select orderId 
From Orders o
Inner Join ItemsBought i on o.orderID = i.orderID
Where itemId = 1) qry1
Inner Join 
(Select orderId 
From Orders o
Inner Join ItemsBought i on o.orderID = i.orderID
Where itemId = 2) qr2 on qry1.orderID = qry2.orderId
Group By orderId
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause.  Here is the MS Access version:

```
select orderId
from ItemsBought ib
where itemId in (1, 2)
group by orderId
having sum(iif(itemId = 1, 1, 0)) > 0 and
       sum(iif(itemId = 2, 1, 0)) > 0;
```

The `having` clause is counting the number of items that match "1" and the number that match "2".  Both of these have to be greater than 0 to meet your condition.

Comment: Would `HAVING Min(itemId = 1) + Min(itemId = 2) = -2` work? (I understand it would be a bit of magic, though)